# kafka producer is not able to update broker after one of the broker is UP

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I know this question is asking many time in stackoverflow but i did not find any proper solution. Please help me if you face this issue.

I have 1 zookeeper and 2 kafka brokers(broker_0, broker_1) and 1 topic with 1 partitions and 2 replication factor. I follow the steps like:

1. Run Zookeeper and 2 kafka broker.(Leader of partition 0 is broker_0)
2. Run Producer using java code and send data to partition 0. (Data sends successfully)
3. Stop broker_0 using ctrl+c and producer automatic connect to broker_1 and sending data successfully.
4. Stop broker_1 using ctrl+c and now producer not send data and show error "Connection to node 1 (/192.168.4.127:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
5. I start broker_0 again but that time producer not update brokers and not connect to broker_0 automatic.

i follow the solution using this link but does not work. [kafka new producer is not able to update metadata after one of the broker is down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704853/kafka-new-producer-is-not-able-to-update-metadata-after-one-of-the-broker-is-dow)

i also enable unclean.leader.election.enable is true in server.properties file but does not work.

i also try metadata.max.age.ms= 100 in producer java file but does not work.

please help me to resolve my problem. i am using kafka_2.13-2.8.0. All my configuration file is below.

## Zookeeper.properties

dataDir=D:\kafka\kafka_2.13-2.8.0\temp\zookeeper

clientPort=2181

maxClientCnxns=0

admin.enableServer=false

## broker_0.properties

broker.id=0

listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.4.127:9092

num.network.threads=3

num.io.threads=8

socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

log.dirs=D:\kafka\kafka_2.13-2.8.0\temp\broker_0

num.partitions=1

num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

offsets.topic.replication.factor=1

transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1

transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

log.retention.hours=168

log.segment.bytes=1073741824

log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

zookeeper.connect=192.168.4.127:2181

zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000

group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0

auto.create.topics.enable=false

default.replication.factor=1

auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true

leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=30

leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=0

unclean.leader.election.enable=true

## broker_1.properties

broker.id=1

listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.4.127:9093

num.network.threads=3

num.io.threads=8

socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

log.dirs=D:\kafka\kafka_2.13-2.8.0\temp\broker_1

num.partitions=1

num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

offsets.topic.replication.factor=1

transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1

transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

log.retention.hours=168

log.segment.bytes=1073741824

log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

zookeeper.connect=192.168.4.127:2181

zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000

group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0

auto.create.topics.enable=false

default.replication.factor=1

auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true

leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=30

leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=0

unclean.leader.election.enable=true

## producer.java file

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try 

{
    String bootstrapServers = "192.168.4.127:9092,192.168.4.127:9093";
    
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "gzip");
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "producer-1");
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG, "1000");
    
    Producer<String, String> producer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<>(properties);
    
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                for(int i=0; i<500; i++)
                {
                    ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("two", 0, "k0", "Hi-"+i);
                    RecordMetadata rmd = producer.send(record).get();
                    producer.flush();
                    
                    System.out.println("Send Thread 1-->[Topic= "+rmd.topic()+", Partition= "+rmd.partition()+", Offset= "+rmd.offset()+", Time= "+rmd.timestamp());
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("exception in thread 1...");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

Zookeeper and all brokers are running same linux system and topic name is "two"

Comment: you state 3 brokers in the bootstrap while saying there are only 2 brokers? not sure if this is causing you issues, check if it make sense

Comment: sorry for this, i have used two bootstrap in java code like: String bootstrapServers = "192.168.4.127:9092,192.168.4.127:9093";

Comment: It shouldn't matter how many brokers you provide as long as one is available and the controller is healthy. SInce all brokers eventually are returned to the client

Comment: @onecricketeer i know it's possible using one bootstrap server. But can you please help me how producer update the broker metadata as i mention in question.?

Comment: @onecricketeer Yes it's true, but as the question suggest it has only 3 instances (1 zkpr , 2 kafka) I was afraid one of the instances in the bootstrap server parameter might unintentionally be related to a zookeeper

Comment: @amit can you share your broker listener and advertising listener configuration?

Comment: AFAIK, Boostrap requests are made only once during a producer lifecycle. But also, you have no retries configuration

Comment: @Ran Lupovich Yeah sure, I have edited my question and share my all config.(1zk, 2 kafka). please check and let me know where i am wrong.